# proving an inequality involving a linear spline / piecewise polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, spline

I have $n+1$ sample points $x_i = \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^4$ and want to approximate the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ by a linear spline $f_n \in S^{1,0}(\mathcal{T_n})$ on the interval $[0,1]$. I know from a theorem that this spline is unique and can be written as
$$
f_n (x) = \sum_i y_i \phi_i(x)
$$
where $y_i = f(x_i)$ and $\phi_i(x)$ are certain hat functions which objey $\phi_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$ and form a basis of the spline space.

What I want to prove is the following:
$$
\max\limits_{x \in \left[0,1\right]} |f_n - f| \leq \frac{C}{n^2}
$$
where $C > 0$ and independent of $n$.

I know an estimate which involves the second derivative of $f$ but for $\sqrt{x}$ this diverges so I don't think that I can apply it. Any suggestions how I can proceed? I tried to use that the $\phi_i$ are bounded by $1$ but this didn't lead me to a sensible esimate.

Comment: What means $S^{1,0},$ and what means ${\cal T}_n$? I saw the notation $S^{1,0}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ on a harmonic analysis professor's chalkboard, so I want to know what it means. (This page is the only website I could find, using Approach0, with this notation.) My guess for $S^{1,0}$ is it's related to the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}$ somehow.

Comment: Hmm... I have used this kind of maths only during the lecture on numerics I was taking at the time. I have never applied it and don't remember any specifics. I can't tell you exactly what the notation $S^{(1,0)}(T_n)$ means but I can tell you what I remember. "S" stands for spline, i.e. we are talking about functions which are piecewise polynmials. The "1" means that we are only using linear polynomial pieces. The second number should be related to the differentiability at the points where we pass from one polynomial to the next ("0" means no differentiability, i.e. sharp bends are possible).

Comment: I don't remember what $T_n$ stands for. You may be able to track down the notation if you have a look at multiple introductory textbooks or lecture notes on numerics. This concept is quite basic. It's just important to look for real math texts and not for texts which mainly tell you how to use spline interpolation. They probably won't use the rigorous math notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a direct comparison between the target $T$ and the approximation $A$. For instance, on the first interval $[0,h_1]$ the error $T-A$ is given by
$$ g(t) = \sqrt{th_1} - t \sqrt{h_1} = (\sqrt{t} - t)\sqrt{h_1}, \quad t \in [0,1].$$
A short calculation establishes that $|g(t)|\leq C \sqrt{h_1}$, but fortunately $h_1 = n^{-4}$, so we can survive the extra square root. I would try a direct comparison on the other subintervals as well.

EDIT: The origin of $g$. Any point $x$ on the interval $[0,h_1]$ can be written as $x=th_1$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Our target is $T = \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{th_1}$. Our approximation $A$ is the value of the spline at the point $x$, i.e. a weighted linear combination of $\sqrt{0}$ and $\sqrt{h_1}$. Specifically, $A = (1-t) \sqrt{0} + t \sqrt{h_1}$. Therefore 
$$ T - A = \sqrt{th_1} - t \sqrt{h_1}.$$
In reality, I did a linear transformation of the interval $[0,h_1]$ into $[0,1]$.

In general, a interpolation polynomial of degree $1$ has this form $$ p(x) = \left(\frac{x-b}{a-b}\right) f(a) + \left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right) f(b). $$
Note that $$\frac{x-b}{a-b} + \frac{x-a}{b-a}=1,$$
which allows us to set $$t =\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$ and write
$$ \tilde{p}(t) = p(x(t)) = (1-t) f(a) + tf(b),$$
effectively transforming the problem to the interval $[0,1]$. Naturally, we must transform $f$ as well and compare $\tilde{p}$ with
$$\tilde{f}(t) = f(x(t)).$$
Personally, I like the representation afford by $\tilde{p}$ because it stresses the fact that I am connecting two points in the plane with a straight line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Carl. I don't understand how you get your g(t). Especially how does the $h_1$ enter? Is this already an estimate for the maximal error?

Comment: @Marc $g$ is a transformation of the error function to the interval $[0,1]$. I have added a few words to this effect.